# Angular PWA - Why browser cache keeps growing? How to stop it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps

I'm wondering is there a way to manage the browser cache and keep it as less as possible in Angular PWA apps.

Growing browser cache in IOS devices fills the cache limit in website data and the app stops working because of that!

Is there a specific configuration for service workers to achieve this?

My current configuration:

```
{
  "index": "/",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/*.css",
        "/*.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**",
        "/profiles/**",
        "/*.(eot|svg|cur|webp|png|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
      ]
    }
  }],
  "dataGroups": [{
    "name": "api",
    "version": 1,
    "urls": ["/api/**"],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "strategy": "freshness",
      "maxSize": 1,
      "maxAge": "7d",
      "timeout": "1s"
    }
  }]
}
```